# lost password for import key file - vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008-sp1

Have the project but the original developer, gone to greener pastures, did not provide the password to import the key file for signing the library. What is the best solution to unlock the file?

Answer (score 1):

1. Contact the original developer.
2. Failing that, get a new keyfile.

Comment: 2. delete old key file and generate a new one?

Comment: Yeah -- there's no way to "unlock" the file without the password (that's the point).